# Checkbox Validation using a hidden field with jquery validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have multiple checkbox inputs that I am trying to create validation for. At least one checkbox has to be selected for the form to submit. What I did was add a hidden input. Then with a change function, there is a join function that combines the checkbox values. Under that there is a variable that checks for the checkboxes' length.

In the jQuery validate, I have tried requiring the field and the parent radio button that produces its associated checkboxes. Then the checkbox fields I have set a min of 1.

Currently, when I hit submit, the form goes through without any of the checkboxes being selected or the parent radio buttons.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var showMe = '';
  /*var checkLength = '';
  $('#interest').val(checkLength);
  console.log(checkLength);*/
  var newStatus = '';
  //Telling whether new is selected
  var usedStatus = '';
  //Telling whether used is selected
  var newSelPush = '';
  var usedSelPush = '';
  $('.equipmentOptionCont').change(function() {
    var newSel = [];
    var usedSel = [];
    //Get new mower options 
    $("input:checkbox[name=newMowerOption]:checked").each(function() {
      newSel.push($(this).val());
      newSelPush = newSel.join(', ');
    });
    //Get used mower options
    $("input:checkbox[name=usedMowerOption]:checked").each(function() {
      usedSel.push($(this).val());
      usedSelPush = usedSel.join(', ');
    });

    //Interest length creation for validation
    var interestCheck = (newSelPush || usedSelPush);
    //Hidden interest input value
    checkLength = interestCheck.length;
    console.log(checkLength);
    $('[name="interestHidden"]').val(checkLength);

  });

  //Validation

  $('#prodNotifForm').validate({
    onfocusout: true,
    rules: {
      interestHidden: {
        //required: true,
        required: $('#newMowerSelect').prop('checked') == true,
        min: 1
      }
    },
    messages: {
      interestHidden: {
        required: "Please choose at least one interest",
        min: "At least one interest needs chosen"
      }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if ($(element).attr('name') == 'interestHidden') {
        error.insertBefore(element.parent('div'));
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element); // <- default
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      //Variables for the form ids
      var notifFirstName = $('#notifFirstName').val();

      $.ajax({
        url: 'subscriberNotifSend.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          'notif_first_name': notifFirstName,

        },
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 
        },
        complete: function() {

        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(textStatus + '|' + errorThrown);
          //console.log('error'); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
        }
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form id="prodNotifForm">
  <div id="interestContainer">
    <input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="newMowerSelect" class="equipmentMainSel notifCheck">
    <label for="newMowerSelect" class="checkMower">
         <div class="labelMowerSelect">New</div>
         <img src="" alt="New Mower Options" class="mowerOptionImgs">
        </label>
    <input type="radio" name="notifymethod" id="usedMowerSelect" class="equipmentMainSel notifCheck">
    <label for="usedMowerSelect" class="checkMower">
         <div class="labelMowerSelect">Used</div>
         <img src="" alt="Used Mower Options" class="mowerOptionImgs">
        </label>
    <div id="interestError"></div>
    <div id="newMowerOptions" class="equipmentOptionCont">
      <p class="notifQuestion">New Mower Options</p>
      <div class="equipmentWrap">
        <label class="equipmentOptions">Ferris</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="newMowerOption" value="Ferris">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="usedMowerOptions" class="equipmentOptionCont">
      <p class="notifQuestion">Used Mower Options</p>
      <div class="equipmentWrap">
        <label class="equipmentOptions">Ferris</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="usedMowerOption" value="Ferris">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="hidden" id="interestHidden" name="interestHidden" value=""></div>
  </div>
  <button id="notifSubmit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You'll have to listen for the `<form>`'s submit event and prevent it.

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You do not execute `$('#prodNotifForm').validate({` on click. You just do that on load. It will prevent the form from submitting unless the rules are passed: https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ - remove `$('#notifSubmit').on('click', function(event) {`

Comment: @Titus Isn't this listening for it? `$('#notifSubmit').on('click', function(event) {` `#notifSubmit` is the submit button in the form.

Comment: @mplungjan When I took off the click function nothing different happened. The form still passes through without requiring the checkbox rules.

Comment: Is not listening for submit but you can still prevent the form from submitting by preventing this event (calling `event.preventDefault()`).

Comment: @Titus How do I make it listen for the form then?

Comment: All of the text inputs in the form are being validated and will stop the form from submitting if not filled in. So I'm not sure how the checkboxes aren't doing the same, when they are in the same form.

Comment: @paul I made a snippet and fixed the missing end brackets and remove the click. You can now actually test the form

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks. This might be easier though - if you go to the link included in this comment. https://optimumwebdesigns.com/admin/gsa/form ... click on the green button to see the form.

Comment: We really really like a [mcve] here. For example you are missing `notifFirstName` in the posted code

Comment: @mplungjan I reduced the code for the question here because the notifFirstName validation is working fine. On the example site, I removed the click function and it changed nothing.

Comment: I get `jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: e[d].call is not a function`

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure why that error displays. The name fields still are validated when that error displays. I honestly have no idea what else to try.